# How to handle errors or try again on publish to pubsub messages google with python

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

Im sending messages to a topic in pubsub with this script:

```
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path("my-project", "my-topic")

while True:
    msg = b"some message"
    future = publisher.publish(topic_path, msg)

    try:
        result = future.result()
    except Exception as ex:
        # handle exception
        print(ex)

    time.sleep(3)
```

My problem is how to make my `print(ex)` to print when a message is not posted on pubsub or detect when message wasn't sent and try to post it again.

Comment: I don't understand the question. I don't know what kind of exceptions get raised, but you can have multiple `except` clauses to catch many different exceptions and do different stuff with each. That way I guess you can detect if the message hasn't been posted or retry or something. Problem is we're kinda lacking context, I don't really get what you want to achieve or what the problem is.

Comment: Exceptions only *appear to be* not caught when calling `publish`! A stack trace is printed out regardless of catching the exception, however the exception is caught and can be handled. It's a weird behavior that the pubsub client library must have implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [article](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publish-with-error-handler) as it implemented error handling for publishing. A method was created for getting callbacks. It accepts future object and data string. If there is an [exception](https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/publisher/api/futures.html#google.cloud.pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future.exception), it will call exception() to return the raised exception.

```
def get_callback(f, data):
    def callback(f):
        try:
            print(f.result())
            futures.pop(data)
        except:  # noqa
            print("Please handle {} for {}.".format(f.exception(), data))

    return callback
```

This method was used to implement get_callback by passing the "future" and "data" parameters. Wherein future is a object and data is string.

```
for i in range(10):
    data = str(i)
    futures.update({data: None})
    # When you publish a message, the client returns a future.
    future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data.encode("utf-8"))
    futures[data] = future
    # Publish failures shall be handled in the callback function.
    future.add_done_callback(get_callback(future, data))
# Wait for all the publish futures to resolve before exiting.
while futures:
    time.sleep(5)
```